# Which texture slot should be used to start where I need 7th and 8th slot together among 0 to 8 index of 9 resources

Tags: c++, directx-11, hlsl, pixel-shader

I have total 9 texture resources among them I need 2 resources together for a pixel shader. In that case what should be the texture slot start index if I need the 7th and 8th texture resources only. (e.g. Texture2D foo1 : register(t7) and  Texture2D foo2 : register(t8))

```
void PSSetShaderResources(
   UINT                     StartSlot,
   UINT                     NumViews,
   ID3D11ShaderResourceView * const *ppShaderResourceViews
);
```

EDIT:
I have a wrapper class for managing shaders where I am dealing with multiple resources like below:

```
ID3D11DeviceContextPtr context = renderer->Context();
std::vector<ID3D11ShaderResourceView*> srvs;

    for(auto texture : m_textures)
    {
        srvs.push_back(texture->ShaderResourceView());
    }
    context->PSSetShaderResources(m_startSlot, srvs.size(), srvs.data());
```

Comment: Unless you need to use all 8 textures in a single shader in one rendering, you don't and shouldn't be binding more than a few at any one time. You should just be using slot 0 and for the dual-texture case, slot 0 & 1.

Comment: So, If I need 7th and 8th then StartSlot should be 7 and for two textures NumVIews should be 2. Is that right?

Comment: I am not sure if you can do that. But you can definitely use multiple calls to set your resource, e.g.

ID3D11ShaderResourceView* textureArray[2];
context->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &textureArray[0]);
context->PSSetShaderResources(1, 1, &textureArray[1]);

startSlot indicates the slot number of device, not the array index of shader resource view.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use ``t0`` and ``t1`` in that shader?

Comment: No, those slots are already in use for other purpose - linear sampling. But Is it possible without doing multiple calls of PSSetShaderResources() ? Unless it's the only way to achieve the purpose.

Comment: I have used following sampler and texture array with other textures if I use start slot 7 debug layer suggests 8 and if I use 8 it suggests 7 as start slot. What should I do?                                                                                                                // Texture and Sampler for video image mixer texture(s)
Texture2D imageMixTexture[5] : register(t7);
SamplerState imageMixSampler[5] : register(s7);

// Texture and Sampler for UYVY converted video image texture
Texture2D imageTexture : register(t8);
SamplerState imageSampler : register(s8);

Comment: @Liton have found that you may provide a resource collection of textures at once and mention a start index from where to collect them from buffer it's provided. So I think start index is related to the collection index which will provided in PSSetShaderResources()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668177/directx-11-send-multiple-textures-to-shader) that you may provide a resource collection of textures at once and mention a start index from where to collect them from buffer it's provided.